# Plotting data in 3-D - Implied Volatility surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

Imagine I have this dataframe:

| Strike | 1.5 | 2.7 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 200 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 300 | 10 | 11 | 13 |

I'd like to plot this dataframe in 3D i.e with strike (e.g xaxis=(100,200,300),yaxis=(1.5   2.7,3) and zaxis the content of the dataframe.

I've never plotted in 3-D in python before and looked into some other questions that were posted on the forum which didn't work for me. How would you do it in matplotlib (or other libraries)?

Comment: I recommend you looking at this link https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/

Comment: Hey @Hamzah thanks for suggesting this it offers some nice solutions to follow up questions I might have. However, on this website, they assume 3 columns x,y,z and they plot those 3 columns. Here I actually have a matrix where x is my 1 first column (without Strike) and y is my first row (without strike). Z is the data inside the matrix. i.e z(100,1.5)=4. This is what I'm trying to plot

Comment: You should first change the format of your dataframe to be able to plot it.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to reformat your dataframe to be able to plot the scatter plot. You can do that with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

coords = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Strike'])
new_cols =  ['x','y','z']
coords.columns = new_cols
coords = coords.apply(pd.to_numeric, axis=1)

print(coords)

    x        y       z
0   100.0   1.5     4.0
1   200.0   1.5     6.0
2   300.0   1.5     10.0
3   100.0   2.7     5.0
4   200.0   2.7     7.0
5   300.0   2.7     11.0
6   100.0   3.0     6.0
7   200.0   3.0     8.0
8   300.0   3.0     13.0

fig = px.scatter_3d(coords, x='x', y='y', z='z')
fig.show()
```

[image]